# SQL Query - Need to get information from different table

Tags: sql, join, count, max

I am trying to write a query to get a report that shows which book has been loaned out the most. I have a query to get the actual book loaned out most, but I need to be able to show the title of that book, which is in another table.

```
SELECT * FROM LOAN;

LOANID     BOOKID     CUSTID OUTDATE   INDATE    DUEDATE

SELECT * FROM BOOK;

AUTHORID     BOOKID   BKISBN   BKSTATUS   BKTITLE  BKSERIES  BKTYPE   BKNUMBER
```

The following query is what I have so far and is getting the bookid.:

```
SELECT Q1.* FROM
(SELECT BOOKID, COUNT(*)
    AS BOOK_COUNT
  FROM LOAN
  GROUP BY LOAN.BOOKID) Q1,
(SELECT MAX(Q2.BOOK_COUNT)
    AS HIGH_COUNT
  FROM (SELECT BOOKID, COUNT(*)
    AS BOOK_COUNT
  FROM LOAN
  GROUP BY LOAN.BOOKID) Q2) Q3
WHERE Q1.BOOK_COUNT = Q3.HIGH_COUNT;
```

RESULT:

```
    BOOKID BOOK_COUNT
---------- ----------
       387          3
```

Now I need BkTitle from the Book Table.

Can anyone assist?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: what DB engine are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
select b.bookid, b.BKTITLE , count(l.loanid) as cnt_loan
from book b
inner join loan l on l.bookid = b.bookid
WHERE ROWNUM < 2
group by b.bookid
order by cnt_loan desc
```

Comment: I am using Oracle SQL Plus. The above code also did not work,

Comment: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: @ReneCanter: if you are using Oracle then try my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have been out of SQL for years, so I am basically starting over. When I use the update, I get ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: @ReneCanter: Ah, I wrote `books`, but table name is `book`. Try again please.

Comment: ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: same error :-)  I am trying to change them around also, I think at least with this, I got a good idea of where to go though.